# How can I get the halfway date of two dates in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, date

I have two date columns in `mm-yy` format and I need to know the halfway date of these two. What formula do I use? I tried simple subtraction of the two dates and then divided it by two but it didn't yield the right result.

[image]

Here's the link to the spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18wUcq_zBV4MdcXTUShYl7N2cx_TBVq9EONSIGvVlsuk/edit#gid=836202959

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the number that's halfway between A2 and B2, use the formula

```
=(A2+B2)/2
```

(You'll need to apply a suitable date format to the output.)

Comment: That was easy, but i missed it.Thanks Live Forever! :)